# Создание нового стека из двух

Tags: стек, c++

Создать интерактивное приложение с возможностью выбора команды: а) ввод данных в стек(и) из стандартного или нестандартного текстового файла(ов); б) вывод данных из всех стеков на экран (стандартный текстовый файл); в) решение задачи; г) освобождение стеков; д) выход.

Сама задача:
Из двух стеков с целыми числами создать новый стек из элементов первого стека, которых нет во втором стеке.

Я так понимаю, ошибка в той части, где сравниваются элементы стеков и создается третий(процедура List* combination), помогите пожалуйста.
Вот код:

```
#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;
#include &lt;stdlib.h&gt;
#include &lt;conio.h&gt;
#include &lt;windows.h&gt;

struct List
{
    int x;
    List *Next;
};
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
List* input(List *MyList1,int &n1)
{
    char name[40];
    printf("\n name dat ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    FILE *tf1=fopen(name,"r");

    int num1;
    fscanf(tf1,"%i",&n1);
    for(int i=0;i&lt;n1;i++)
    {
        fscanf(tf1,"%i",&num1);
        if(i==0)
        MyList1-&gt;x=num1;
        else
        {
            List *tmp=new List;
            tmp-&gt;x=num1;
            tmp-&gt;Next=MyList1;
            MyList1=tmp;
        }

    }
    return MyList1;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void print(List *MyList1, List *MyList2, List *MyList3,int &n1, int &n2,int &n3)
{
    List *temp1=MyList1;
    List *temp2=MyList2;
    List *temp3=MyList3;
    printf("\n &#1055;&#1086;&#1082;&#1072;&#1079;&#1072;&#1090;&#1100; &#1089;&#1090;&#1077;&#1082; \n");
    printf(" 1 - &#1089;&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;: \n");
    for(int i=0;i&lt;n1;i++)
    {
        printf(" %i",temp1-&gt;x);
        temp1=temp1-&gt;Next;
    }
    printf("\n 2 - &#1089;&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;: \n");
    for(int i=0;i&lt;n2;i++)
    {
        printf(" %i",temp2-&gt;x);
        temp2=temp2-&gt;Next;
    }
    printf("\n 3 - &#1089;&#1090;&#1077;&#1082;: \n");
    for(int i=0;i&lt;n3;i++)
    {
        printf(" %i",temp3-&gt;x);
        temp3=temp3-&gt;Next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void clear(List *MyList1, List *MyList2, List *MyList3,int &n1, int &n2,int &n3)
{
    MyList1=new List;
    MyList2=new List;
    MyList3=new List;
    n1=0;n2=0;n3=0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
List* combination(List *MyList1, List *MyList2, List *MyList3,int &n1, int &n2,int &n3)

{
    List *temp1=MyList1;
    List *temp2=MyList2;
    List *temp3=MyList3;
    for(int i=0;i&lt;n1;i++)
    {
        bool flag=false;
        temp1-&gt;x;
        for(int i=0;i&lt;n1;i++)
        {
            temp2-&gt;x;
            if (temp1==temp2)
            {
                flag=true;
            }
        }
        if (flag!=true)
        {
            MyList3-&gt;Next=temp1;
            n3+=1;
        }
    }
    return MyList3;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    List *MyList1=new List;
    List *MyList2=new List;
    List *MyList3=new List;
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n1,n2,n3=0;
    char c;
    while (1)
    { //clrscr();
        printf("\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        puts(" A - INPUT");
        puts(" B - SHOW STACKS");
        puts(" C - CREATE NEW STACK");
        puts(" D - CLEAR");
        puts(" E - EXIT");
        c=getch();
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'A':MyList1=input(MyList1,n1);MyList2=input(MyList2,n2);break;
            case 'B':print(MyList1, MyList2 ,MyList3,n1,n2,n3);break;
            case 'C':MyList3=combination(MyList1, MyList2 ,MyList3,n1,n2,n3);break;
            case 'D':clear(MyList1, MyList2 ,MyList3,n1,n2,n3);break;
            case 'E':return 0;
            default : puts(" &#1054;&#1096;&#1080;&#1073;&#1082;&#1072;!");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: есть еще такой вариант проблемного куска..
результат близок к нужному, но все же что-то не так


`List* combination(List *MyList1, List *MyList2, List *MyList3,int &n1, int &n2,int &n3)
{
List *temp1=MyList1;
List *temp2=MyList2;
List *temp3=MyList3;
for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
bool flag=false;
temp1->x;
for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
temp2->x;
if (temp1==temp2)
{
flag=true;
}
}
if (flag!=true)
{
temp1=MyList1;
MyList1=MyList1-> Next;
temp1->Next=MyList3;
MyList3=temp1;
n3+=1;
}
}
return MyList3;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Ой, а зачем так много кода? Если вы считаете, что проблема в `combination`, то включите в пример только `combination` плюс хардкодированные тестовые данные, воспроизводящие проблему.

Код наподобие `printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");` точно не обязателен для понимания проблемы.

И ещё: вас не затруднит писать лесенкой?

---

Кстати: http://www.sscce.org/